# jQuery replace ],[ with comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my string like this :

```
[[{"en":"Search\r\n","fr":"Chercher","it":"Cercare"}],[{"en":"MORE INFORMATION:","fr":"PLUS D'INFORAMTION:","it":"Informazioni:"}],[{"en":"Why choose us ?","fr":"Pourquoi nous choisir ?","it":"Perché scegliere noi?"}],[{"en":"Here are the main values that will lead you to choose ELGATEK for your IT project:","fr":"Voici les principales valeurs qui vous amèneront à choisir ELGATEK pour votre projet Informatique :","it":"I valori chiave che portano a scegliere ELGATEK per il vostro progetto IT:"}],[{"en":"CREATIVITY & INNOVATION","fr":"CRÉATIVITÉ & INNOVATION","it":"Creatività e Innovazione"}]
```

I want to replace all occurrence this part string `],[` with comma.
I tried `str.replace('],[',',')` but it works only on the first occurrence. 
Please help.

Comment: try `str.replace(/],\[/g, ',')`

Comment: Do a loop then? Or search how to replace all with regex.

Comment: Are you sure it's a string

Comment: it a json object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your string should replace like this:

```js
var str = '[[{"en":"Search\r\n","fr":"Chercher","it":"Cercare"}],[{"en":"MORE INFORMATION:","fr":"PLUS D\'INFORAMTION:","it":"Informazioni:"}],[{"en":"Why choose us ?","fr":"Pourquoi nous choisir ?","it":"Perché scegliere noi?"}],[{"en":"Here are the main values that will lead you to choose ELGATEK for your IT project:","fr":"Voici les principales valeurs qui vous amèneront à choisir ELGATEK pour votre projet Informatique :","it":"I valori chiave che portano a scegliere ELGATEK per il vostro progetto IT:"}],[{"en":"CREATIVITY & INNOVATION","fr":"CRÉATIVITÉ & INNOVATION","it":"Creatività e Innovazione"}]]';

console.log(str.replace(/\[\{/g, '{').replace(/\}\]/g, '}'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You try:

```
str.replace(/],\[/g, ',')
```

Comment: `[` should be escaped, not `]`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve that :

```
let s = "[[{\"en\":\"Search\\r\\n\",\"fr\":\"Chercher\",\"it\":\"Cercare\"}],[{\"en\":\"MORE INFORMATION:\",\"fr\":\"PLUS D'INFORAMTION:\",\"it\":\"Informazioni:\"}],[{\"en\":\"Why choose us ?\",\"fr\":\"Pourquoi nous choisir ?\",\"it\":\"Perché scegliere noi?\"}],[{\"en\":\"Here are the main values that will lead you to choose ELGATEK for your IT project:\",\"fr\":\"Voici les principales valeurs qui vous amèneront à choisir ELGATEK pour votre projet Informatique :\",\"it\":\"I valori chiave che portano a scegliere ELGATEK per il vostro progetto IT:\"}],[{\"en\":\"CREATIVITY & INNOVATION\",\"fr\":\"CRÉATIVITÉ & INNOVATION\",\"it\":\"Creatività e Innovazione\"}]]\n";
var result = s.split('],[').join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to just use `JSON.parse`, then map the array. You can still stringify it if you really need it as a string, however I suppose you want to get an array of objects anyway.

```js
let s = "[[{\"en\":\"Search\\r\\n\",\"fr\":\"Chercher\",\"it\":\"Cercare\"}],[{\"en\":\"MORE INFORMATION:\",\"fr\":\"PLUS D'INFORAMTION:\",\"it\":\"Informazioni:\"}],[{\"en\":\"Why choose us ?\",\"fr\":\"Pourquoi nous choisir ?\",\"it\":\"Perché scegliere noi?\"}],[{\"en\":\"Here are the main values that will lead you to choose ELGATEK for your IT project:\",\"fr\":\"Voici les principales valeurs qui vous amèneront à choisir ELGATEK pour votre projet Informatique :\",\"it\":\"I valori chiave che portano a scegliere ELGATEK per il vostro progetto IT:\"}],[{\"en\":\"CREATIVITY & INNOVATION\",\"fr\":\"CRÉATIVITÉ & INNOVATION\",\"it\":\"Creatività e Innovazione\"}]]\n";
let p = JSON.parse(s).map(e => e[0]);
console.log(p);
// if you really need it as a string:
console.log(JSON.stringify(p));
```